# Given an array of integers ‘num’ return the array incremented by 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, increment

Given an array of integers, return a new array that has that original values incremented by 1.

Each value in the array can't exceed 9 and you can't use any function that converts the array into an integer.

i.e:

```
Original Array = [1,2,7,9]
Returned Array = [2,3,8,0]
```

@param (array) num
@return (array)

This is what I am currently doing. Just wondering if there is anything that will be more efficient.

```
function increment (num) {
    for (var i = num.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        num[i]++;
        if (num[i] > 9) num[i] = 0;
        else break;
    }
    return num;
}

console.log(increment([1, 2, 7, 9]));
```

Comment: Why aren't 1 and 2 incremented, in your example?

Comment: Because we want to increment the array as a number, so the number here would be 1279. Icrement that and we get 1280, and we return that as an array: [1, 2, 8, 0]

Comment: then just do `1 + parseInt(arr.join(''))`. then you could just split it again

Comment: @JohnRuddell he said no array to int conversion

Comment: @bryan60 ah, well you could still cheat, but this looks more like an interview question so probably should just go through and increment the values needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one problem: if the input array is composed of all 9s, you want a desired output of, eg, `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]` (rather than `[0, 0, 0, 0]`):

```js
function increment (num) {
    for (var i = num.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        num[i]++;
        if (num[i] > 9) {
          num[i] = 0;
          if (i === 0) {
            // Last iteration, but we need to carry - unshift a 1:
            num.unshift(1);
          }
        }
        else break;
    }
    return num;
}


console.log(increment([1, 2, 7, 9]));
console.log(increment([3, 9, 9, 9]));
console.log(increment([9, 9, 9, 9]));
console.log(increment([1, 1, 1, 1]));
```

Comment: I was just about to post essentially this! (handling the edge case) beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

A little late but here's a recursive version, same edge case issue if the argument is `[9,9,9,9]`.

```js
function increment(array, index = NaN) {
    if (isNaN(index)) {
        index = array.length - 1;
    }
    if (++array[index] % 10 === 0) {
        array[index] = 0;
        increment(array, --index);
    }
    return array;
}

console.log(increment([1,2,7,9]))
console.log(increment([9,9,9,9]))
```